# How do components interact in Redux + ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am interested, how do ReactJS components interact with each other, when used in couple with Redux?

From what I've seen in the [todoApp tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html), I created a diagram how *I understand* that interaction *(this may be totally incorrect and this is why am I asking this question)*:

[image: my personal vision of how react + redux work]

On this diagram one can see five basic entities: `Provider`, `Store`, `Container`, `MainComponent` and `Component`.

For simplicity, let's call all this system **an application**, which, by fact, consists of one compound component, `MainComponent` and its children.

`Provider` is a component, encapsulating both `Store` and `Container` instances.

`Container` is an enhanced version of `MainComponent`, powered with Redux' `dispatch()` function and containing rafinated (filtered) data from the `currentState` of the `Store` instance.

`Store` is just a holder of `currentState`, the actual application' state.

`MainComponent` is, as described before, the central component of an application, made of `Component` instances *(optionally)*.

---

Now, there are four Redux functions on this diagram, namely `connect`, `selector`, `reducer` and `dispatch`.

`selector` filters the `state`, giving the data which is required by `MainComponent` and throwing away everything else.

`connect` takes `selector` function and `MainComponent` class and provides the new, `Container` class, which then is used in `Provider` component to fill the `MainComponent` with the data.

`reducer` takes the current application' state and a dispatched action *(which has an aim to change the current state)* and gives a new, changed application' state.

`dispatch` is the function, joining all those previous ones together. This one *"changes"* the state of the `MainComponent`. It takes an `action`, then hits `Store` for the current application' state. The fetched state and action are passed to the `reducer` function, which gives the new application state. This new state is stored as the `currentState` inside the `Store` and then is passed to the `selector` function, which filters the state, taking only what is needed by `MainComponent` and then updates the `props` for `MainComponent` and makes it to re-render itself.

---

So is this simplified data flow/interaction diagram correct? Or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Comment: No fundamental misunderstanding, but I suggest you read Redux's code (very short) so you get the full picture instead of deciphering stuff from user-land implementation and perceived behavior.